# How can I restrict downloads for specific users?

Tags: traffic-shaping

I am running an Active directory and I need to specifically restrict downloads to some users while being able to surf the web...
Is there a tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a proxy is the ideal solution.  Be sure to document what you do and do not allow.  If you need a web filtering solution (rather than dealing with your own access lists), there are many commercial products available.

And if you're going to install a proxy, be sure that it's not possible to browse the outside Web without it.  Users can be tricky sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

try [untangle](http://www.untangle.com/). It's open source but requires a separate PC to run. There is also OpenDNS. Before you start blocking you should put in place a company policy and notify your employees accordingly. Once a policy is defined then start blocking as per the policy.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a proxy that's smart enough to do it and send all web traffic to it.

One example would be Squid with ntlm_auth and some custom ACLs.